# Rails cache redis with TLS - Server closed the connection (EOFError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I am using [Digital Ocean managed Redis 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/managed-databases-redis) database but I cannot connect.

The url is:
`ENV.fetch("REDIS_CACHE_URL")`

```
rediss://default:password@redis-cache-do-user-id.b.db.ondigitalocean.com:25061/0"
```

**config**

```
config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, {
  driver: :hiredis, 
  url: ENV.fetch("REDIS_CACHE_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" },
  :ssl => true,
  ssl_params: { verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE },
}
```

Caching return false

```
Rails.cache.write('test', 1) => false
```

**Rails.cache.stats**

```
/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/redis-4.7.1/lib/redis/client.rb:306:in `rescue in io': Connection lost (ECONNRESET) (Redis::ConnectionError)
/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/hiredis-0.6.3/lib/hiredis/ext/connection.rb:21:in `rescue in read': Connection reset by peer (Errno::ECONNRESET)
/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/hiredis-0.6.3/lib/hiredis/ext/connection.rb:19:in `read': Server closed the connection (EOFError)
```

**Redis cache exists?**

```
> redis = Redis.new(url: ENV.fetch("REDIS_CACHE_URL"))
 => #<Redis client v4.7.1 for rediss://redis-cache-do-user-id-0.b.db.... 
> redis.exists?("some_key")
/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/redis-4.7.1/lib/redis/client.rb:306:in `rescue in io': Connection lost (ECONNRESET) (Redis::ConnectionError)
/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/hiredis-0.6.3/lib/hiredis/ext/connection.rb:21:in `rescue in read': Connection reset by peer (Errno::ECONNRESET)
/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/hiredis-0.6.3/lib/hiredis/ext/connection.rb:19:in `read': Server closed the connection (EOFError)
```

I can correctly connect to redis-cli from the same machine (localhost)

```
redis-cli --tls -h redis-cache-do-user-id-0.b.db.ondigitalocean.com -a XXXXXXXXXX -p 25061
Warning: Using a password with '-a' or '-u' option on the command line interface may not be safe.
redis-cache-do-user-id-0.b.db.ondigitalocean.com:25061> KEYS *
1) "test"
redis-cache-do-user-id-0.b.db.ondigitalocean.com:25061>
```

Using other vendor (like RedisLabs) it works. So maybe the issue is something related to connecting from Rails using TLS.

Comment: Don't you have to provide the `ssl_params` with the certs if connecting over ssl?  In my case I had all the certs configured but was missing `ssl: true` - so glad I found this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `REDIS_CACHE_URL` is not correct.
You should confirm the URL is correct

```
$redis = Redis.new(url: ENV.fetch("REDIS_CACHE_URL"))
$redis.exists?("some_key")
```

Comment: It returns "Server closed the connection (EOFError)" (as described above for Rails.cache.stats). The ENV.fetch("REDIS_CACHE_URL") is correctly present.